# How to edit zen coding shortcut on Coda for MAC

Tags: shortcut, coda, emmet

I've installed zen coding for coda, the TEA for coda plugin.
I'm trying to edit my shortcut to expand abbreviation, I'm already on my TextActions.plist file, but when i Edit the shortcut line, that doesn't work... I'm not sure if i'm spelling it right, take a look:

```
<key>Expand Abbreviation</key>
    <dict>
        <key>action</key>
        <string>TEAZenActions</string>
        <key>options</key>
        <dict>
            <key>action</key>
            <string>expand_abbreviation</string>
        </dict>
        <key>shortcut</key>
        <string>Command+F1</string>
        <key>submenu</key>
        <string>Zen Coding</string>
    </dict>
```

I'm putting Command+F1 but it's not working, i know the changes are taking effect because the default shortcut isn't working anymore. the "^e" shortcut.

I would like to put the shortcut "Command+Enter" to expand my abbreviations, any ideas how should I type that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Mac OS, go to System Preferences > Keyboard > Keyboard Shortcuts, choose Application Shortcuts, click on + button to add new shortcut and follow the instructions.

Comment: thanks man, I've find out that I had to re-install zen coding on ST2 and then the TAB shortcut worked fine :)